# What's wrong with the use of these classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I'm trying to call the function **login()** however as you can see it is not defined meaning that I have completely got the wrong idea of classes - I'm trying to comprehend there uses and as you can see I'm hardly even a beginner at using them.

[Screenshot of code in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9bbT.png)

Thanks for any help or tip!

Comment: Please don't put your code/error as an image. Write them in your question using code formatting (indent by 4 spaces)

Comment: It’s `self.login()`, but it doesn’t make sense to use classes like that. Just define some functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to write this class:

```
class Menu_choice():
    def login(self):
        print("Login")
    def register(self):
        pring("Register")
    def __init__(self, choice):
        self.choice = choice
        if self.choice == "LOGIN":
            self.login()
        if self.choice == "REGISTER":
            self.register()
```

But as others have pointed out, this class as such does not make any sense. I think you want something like this:

```
class Menu_choice():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def login(self):
        print("Login")
    def register(self):
        print("Register")
    def __call__(self, choice):
        self.choice = choice
        if self.choice == "LOGIN":
            self.login()
        if self.choice == "REGISTER":
            self.register()

choice = input("Would you like to login or register?: ").upper()
m = Menu_choice()
m(choice)
```

You can make an instatiate your class as `m` but also define a `__call__()` funtion which will be executed when you call the instance like `m(choice)`

Comment: Forgive me for my incompetency and thank you for the solution!